# What is the result of synthesis?

Tags: verilog, vlsi

I'm trying to implement to gate as follows.
But i'm not sure how does it synthesis to gate?

case 1

```
wire [3:0] A, B, C, D;  
always @(posedge CLK)
    begin
        C=B;
        B=A;
        A=D;
    end
```

case 2

```
wire [3:0] A, B, C, D;
always @(posedge CLK)
    begin
        A=D;
        C=B;
        B=A;
     end
```

Also.

case 3

```
wire [3:0] A, B, C, D;
always @(posedge CLK)
    begin
C<=B;
B<=A;
A<=D;
    end
```

case 4

```
wire [3:0] A, B, C, D;
always @(posedge CLK)
    begin
A<=D;
C<=B;
B<=A;
    end
```

Does anyone know how to synthesized to gate?
Would you please illustrate this one?

Comment: Why don't you use any IDE (i.e. Altera Quartus II or Xilinx Vivado) to find out?

Comment: @Qiu  Altera Quartus II or Xilinx Vivado are these free? and Can I know the result of synthesis to illustrate as gate?

Comment: You can use free version of Quartus and Vivado to illustrate synthesised system.

Comment: @Qiu Thanks What is the main difference between Vivado and ISE?

Comment: Vivado is ISE's successor, but it supports only new Xilinx fpgas (v7).

Comment: @Qui Thanks Sir Your answer was helpful to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of those examples should compile, The variables should be of type `reg`:

`D` Needs to be declared regarding how it is generated.

```
reg [3:0] A, B, C;
always @(posedge CLK) begin
  A<=D;
  C<=B;
  B<=A;
end
```

Here A,C and B will synthesis to flip-flops. The order of A,C and B does not matter. They describe parallel hardware.